# why a process is known as abstraction in operating systems?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

This is a basic question but as I could not conclude after reading several documents also, so I am posting it.

Why a process is known as abstraction in Operating systems? Is it because it gives us the concept of using virtual processor and virtual memory?

Comment: Maybe you should tell which documents did you read....

Comment: I was going through [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29 and [link]http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/9788131715482/overview/ch01lev1sec5. In later one it is mentioned "The concept of a process is fundamental in the domain of operating systems. The operating system keeps track of many concurrent program executions, all in the abstraction of different processes.". But I want to know Is this the only thing for saying it abstraction.

Comment: You need to read more books.... and take many hours or days to read about OSes and/or Linux!!!

Comment: Odd to tag this as [tag:linux].  For MMU/no-MMU, there is/isn't memory protection.  Some OS's only provide for *thread* like processes.  What is a process?  I think it is abstract in that it is only schedule-able.  Some OSs do not have file systems. `mmap()`, `pthreads()`, etc.  By tagging the question Linux, you have made it somewhat concrete.

Answer (score 2):

Read the wikipages about [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system), [process management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_management_%28computing%29), [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29), [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), [fork system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29).

I'll say that process is an [abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) since it is not provided by the hardware (under the kernel) and it hide details. Also, processes are generally somehow isolated because they provide some protection: if a process A misbehaves (i.e. crashes), it usually does not alter the behavior of some unrelated process B.

A Linux process state is much more that virtual memory and virtual processor: it also contains file descriptor, stack, signal handling and mask, etc... Read [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [daemon(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html), [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [glibc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glibc.7.html), [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) man pages.

Take several hours or days to read a good book like [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); it contains several chapters related to your question.

And reading good books about Operating systems (e.g. by [Tanenbaum](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/pearsonhigheredus/educator/product/products_detail.page?isbn=0136006639) or by [Silberschatz, Galbin, Gagne](http://os-book.com/)) should help.

I recommend the [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) textbook (which is freely downloadable).

Comment: Not only linux processes have stacks, all processes, as far as I know, have a stack. Processes in general consist of 3 things: a stack, data and a program counter..

Comment: The stack might stay nearly empty (in principle). Read Appel's paper *Garbage Collection Can be Faster than Stack Allocation* for the insight (continuation passing style)

Answer (score 1):

abstractions can be processes, files,address spaces and interprocess communication.(anything that hides details other than relevant details)